# Why My Program not working successful?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

My app was not working it was halt when save option select. Where is the bug?

```
    [bits 16]
    [org 0x7d00]

    ;Start
start:
    mov ah,00
    mov al,03h
    int 10h
    mov ax,0a00h
    mov es,ax
keys:
    mov ax,10h
    int 16h
    cmp al,'1'
    je new
    cmp al,'2'
    je load
    jmp keys
new:
    mov cx,1
    mov dx,1
    int 10h
    mov ax,0013h
    int 10h
.key:
    pusha ;save regs
    mov ax,10h
    int 16h
    cmp al,' '
    je .draw_pix
    cmp al,'w'
    je .up
    cmp al,'s'
    je .down
    cmp al,'a'
    je .left
    cmp al,'d'
    je .right
    cmp al,'q'
    je start
    cmp al,'e'
    je save
    cmp al,'c'
    je clear
    cmp al,'r'
    je load
    cmp al,'p'
    je save
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.draw_pix :
    popa
    mov ah,0x0C
    int 10h
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.up:
    popa
    dec dx
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.down:
    popa
    inc dx
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.left:
    popa
    dec cx
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.right:
    popa
    inc cx
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.inccolor:
    popa
    inc al
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
.deccolor:
    popa
    dec al
    jmp .key
    ;---------------------
load:
    ;....

clear:
    mov ax,0013h
    int 10h
    jmp keys
save:
    mov cx,0
    mov dx,0
.read:
    add [Buffer],cx
    add [Buffer],dx
    add [Buffer],al
    mov ah,0x0D
    int 10h
.getx:
    cmp cx,319
    je .gety
    inc cx
    jmp .read
.gety:
    cmp dx,199
    je start
    inc dx
    mov cx,0
    jmp .read

exit:
    ret

Buffer times 512 dw 0
```

I can't under stand why this was halting? Save func. is must be read pixels and write the buffer:X,Y,Color but it always going halt. I tried this in my os.Thanks.

Comment: No offense but if only you structured your code well, the problem would either not be present or be easy to spot. `save` actually pretty much does something else than what you implied. It puts 0 into `cx` and `dx`, then it runs through `.read`, `.getx`, `.gety` and then eventually starts the whole program all over again (`je start`) or simply gets stuck in a `.read`->`.getx`->`.gety` "loop". What are you trying to do?

Comment: Subroutines are not jumped to, but called. Learn how to do call subroutines from x86 and modify your code. Also comment it, I'm not going to read uncommented assembly.

Comment: I am trying pixel paint but do you think it was working?

Comment: if its calls ,maybe. Will not jump?

Comment: @m0skit0 I'd rather prefer well written clean code over comments.

Comment: I can't edit code because now i am on tablet

Comment: @m0skit0 Ahhh, you're one of the "oldschool" guys... You'll never believe in clean code, I know. I've already met dozens of your kind. Well, do the hackity-hackity at your pleasure, I don't care as long as I don't need to work with you. Btw, how come that *I myself* didn't code in ASM, but *you* are the one who is not reading it if it's not commented? FYI, nobody ever had problems maintaining my code since it is always written properly and is describing itself. And to not break your incredible awesomness I'm not going to tell about my pure x86 Asm OS...

Comment: @m0skit0 Look, it is absolutely unnecessary to act like a child. Nobody would even care that you think you're superior while I am and my colleagues are stupid. Actually, you are the one who sounds pretty much like inventing stories for that matter. But that's your business, I don't care. And btw this page is about Abdulkadir's question, not your superiority.

Comment: @Powerslave Who told you're stupid? I'm talking seriously. If you have thousands of lines of code in assembly and you work with no delay without comments, you're a genius to me. Anyone who does is a genius, so your colleagues are geniuses. Anyway, you're right, this page is about Abdulkadir question, but let me remind you you started the discussion. Have a nice day, sir (if "genius" feels offensive...).

Comment: @m0skit0 Mate, I just mentioned that experience (not only mine, but of thousands of developers) proved that good structuring of code, straightforward and consistent naming, applying patterns, etc. is generally a better idea than having comments all over the place. If you prefer comments, go with them. I'd still prefer them kept to the minimum and having the code explain itself. Throughout the years, comments turned out to be not only disturbing sometimes, but also error prone. I never inteneded to offend you with that, but to add to your very comment that I actually agreed.

Comment: @Powerslave Why do I have to do either structured code OR comments? Why can't they go along? Why would I waste time trying to figure out what a bunch of code does (even if it's structured and easy to read) for say 5 minutes if I can read one comment in 10 seconds and understand it? Anyway, I'm out of this discussion since you were right before: this is not the place to discuss this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of using subroutines is (example only):

```
mySubroutine:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp

    mov ax,[ss:bp + 4]    ; load first parameter into AX
    mov bx,[ss:bp + 6]    ; load second parameter into BX

    ; do work here

    mov sp,bp
    pop bp
ret

; ...

; push parameters from right to left, invoke mySubroutine
; and clean up stack afterwards
mov ax,9
push ax    ; push the second parameter onto the stack
mov ax,7
push ax    ; push the first parameter onto the stack
call mySubroutine
add sp,4
```

*Please note that the added comments are there only for "beginners' hint", and are completely unnecessary or even disturbing in live professional code*

**For more information, see [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).**

I'd recommend *cdecl* along with adding "C function signature comments" at the top of each subroutine:

```
; void print(char* text)
_print:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp

    ; ...

    mov sp,bp
    pop bp
ret
```

Comment: Thanks but i have a one question to ask .Can i ask?

Comment: @AbdulkadirÇakır Of course! That's what *StackOverflow* is for :)

Comment: I want to write this buffer to hdd.do you think it Will give error else succesful?and how can i Decode  my written x,y,Color?

Comment: @AbdulkadirÇakır Try to explain your intents in a larger scope. What would the application be for? Is it some kind of primitive "paint software"? Are you going the write the data to raw disk? What does the buffer contain?

Comment: Yes it was paint software and viewer i am using nasm and yes i wanna write Raw disk with int 13h ,buffer contain cx dx and al (x ,y,Color) and how may i get values in buffer?

Comment: @AbdulkadirÇakır Based on the `[org 0x7d00]` line, I assume that you're trying to run this thing right after booting, without an operating system; loading it just after the MBR. Although I don't really have time to present a complete solution, I'd say I'd suggest to, at first, use subroutines properly (`call` and `ret`), wrap the ugly interrupt calls in subroutines with communicative names and break up your application in nice, little pieces that are easy to read/understand/maintain/troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks @Powerslave.if you have  os ,can you send me with source?

Comment: @AbdulkadirÇakır I'm at the office right now. I don't have it here with me, but there are several other examples available online like **[MenuetOS](http://www.menuetos.net/)**. They're frequently not of the best quality but are pretty much fine for studying the internal workings of such a system.